# See who invited a discord bot (js)

Tags: discord.js

I would like to log when my bot joins servers (i already have the base code) I just need to know how to define the owner of the server! if you know how to do this please help me!

Comment: [`Guild#owner`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/reply-prefix/class/Guild?scrollTo=owner)

Answer (score 0):

Well, from the "guildCreate" event, you recieve a [Guild](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild) class. From which you can access the owner GuildMember class. Then you can get the information about the owner that.

Here is an example:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("guildCreate", (guild) => {
  console.log(`I have been added to a new guild! ${guild.name}
  Owner name: ${guild.owner.user.username}`);
})

client.login("yourToken")
```

It's the best to read thru the docs.

Answer (score 0):

For checking who invited :

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.on("guildCreate", async guild => {
    const fetchedLogs = await guild.fetchAuditLogs({
        limit: 1,
        type: "BOT_ADD"
    });
    const auditlog = fetchedLogs.entries.first();
    let myChannel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id == YOUR_CHANNEL_ID);
    myChannel.send(auditlog.executor.tag + " added bot in "+ guild.name+"\nOwner is: 
    "guild.owner.user.username);
    });
```

Also you can check for **VIEW_AUDIT_LOGS** permission